# How do I debug or fix ng serve giving a 400 error?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I would like to run my Angular app using `ng serve` so I can do some development and see the results in real-time.

1. I run this command: `ng serve --ssl --open`
2. It takes a few seconds to compile/build.
3. It reports back: `Date: 2020-07-28T14:01:07.382Z - Hash: ******** - Time: 20167ms ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on https://localhost:4200/ ** i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.`
4. This opens Chrome to https://localhost:4200/
5. I get an error page shown below.
6. In developer tools, there is a **400 Bad Request** error response.  I don't know why.
   [image]

I tried using the `--verbose` option on `ng serve`, but I only get verbose build messages - nothing about the request itself or why a GET is a bad request.

My Angular version is:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
```

Comment: Can you remove the `-ssl`
 option from the command? Final result will be: `ng serve --open`. Then report back.

Comment: Hi @Danizavtz, If I remove the `--ssl` option, I get this error in Chrome: **This site can’t provide a secure connection. localhost sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**

Comment: Yeah, you have to access your application without the `https` in url bar. Try to access `http://localhost:4200`. Try in a incognito mode and new tab (just for cache clean).

Comment: I had to add `http://localhost:4200` as an allowed host with my server app CORS policy, but now it is working.  My authentication scheme will not work without the `--ssl` option, but luckily I can use my app in an anonymous mode, so I do not need that right now.  This is a workaround, but I can now do the development I needed to do.  Thanks @Danizavtz.

Comment: Update answer with a flow using self-signed certificates.

Comment: Thank you!  I am very busy right now.  I finished the hotfix and I am moving on to other things, but I will try this probably on Monday.  (says the dev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve your application with ssl certificates you need to generate ssl certificates.

You may need to download the **openssl** command if you do not have it.

In my example I am using self signed certificates just to run an application in development environment (localhost).
Just generate new self-signed certificates with command:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout localhost.key -days 3560 -out localhost.crt
```

Just answer the questions prompted and it will generate two files a `.crt` and a `.key`.

In your angular application root folder copy/paste the two files generated.

After that  just run the command:

```
ng serve --ssl --ssl-key certs/localhost.key --ssl-cert certs/localhost.crt
```

Now it will serve your application with https enabled. This warning will show,  you can ignore (for development environment), click `advanced`.

[image: insecuremsg]

After that just click `proceed to localhost`

[image: insecuremsg2]

And here is the evidence accessing with https:

[image: localhost https enabled]

## Instructions to access without ssl

The option `-ssl` is a parameter to serve your application with `https` protocol. As stated by the [angular cli documentation](https://angular.io/cli/serve#arguments).

In order to fix this, you need to remove the `-ssl` option from your current `ng serve` command invocation.

The invocation should be:

```
ng serve
```

After that you should access your application without the `https`. In your application url.

Just open a browser in incognito mode and a new tab (for browser cache clean purpose).

```
http://localhost:4200
```

Notice that, the default port is being used (`port 4200`). You have to access the url according to your current configuration.

As stated by the @Jess (original poster), to ensure no communication problems with your backend, you have to enable CORS policy (in your backend) to your current address being served by the frontend (currently http://localhost:4200).

Comment: +1 for your help.  Thanks!  I'm reserving the 'accepted answer' because I will want to use ssl eventually, but I can work around that for now.

Comment: This works for me in FireFox, but not Chrome.  Odd.

Comment: If you see the prints, its chrome I can show my configuration